# How can I control bash's brace expansion to do the right thing (which zsh does automatically)?

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

In zsh, I get the expected result from both of these brace expansions:

```
$ touch file-{001..100}
$ touch file-{1..100}
```

The first one gives me files named file-001, file-002, etc., all the way to file-100.  The second one gives me files named file-1, file-2, etc., all the way to file-100.

In bash, however, both give me files named file-1, file-2, etc.  This strikes me as a pretty major bug (or design flaw) in bash's brace expansion.

Is there any way to configure bash to do the right thing in this case?

Comment: What version of bash are you working with? Works for me with `$BASH_VERSION = 4.1.10(4)-release`

Comment: The server I tested this on uses returns `himBH 3.00.16(1)-release` from `echo $- $BASH_VERSION`.  Locally I get `himvBH 3.2.17(1)-release`.   Both expand to 1-100 instead of 001-100.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in older versions of bash, fixed in bash 4.1 alpha. From the [changelog](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES):

> mm. Fixed a bug that in brace expansion that caused zero-prefixed terms to not contain the correct number of digits.

Comment: Was that bug fixed by Lumberg, by any chance?

Comment: @l0b0 I don't know; is the bash repository even public? And who's Lumberg and why would it matter who fixed the bug anyway?

Comment: Pop culture reference. Don't worry about it.